# Tab row indication getting delayed when clicked - Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am implementing a tab row in which there in two tabs inside. But when I click on the tabs the indication is getting delayed. The tab is showing the ripple first and then the background color is changing then the background text is changing.Is there any way to make it smoooth.

Libraries used:

```
  //pager
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager:0.21.2-beta"
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager-indicators:0.21.2-beta"
```

Is there any way to solve it? Here is my code.

```
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = Color.Gray
            ) {
                var tabIndex by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(0) }
                val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
                val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
                val tabTitles = listOf<String>("First", "Second", "Third")
                val white = Color(0xffffffff)
                val ash7a = Color(0xff7a7a7a)
                val pearl = Color(0xff10CFC9)


                Column {
                    TabRow(selectedTabIndex = tabIndex,
                        backgroundColor = Color.White,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(top = 24.dp)
                            .background(color = Color.Transparent)
                            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(25.dp)),
                        indicator = { tabPositions ->
                            TabRowDefaults.Indicator(
                                Modifier
                                    .pagerTabIndicatorOffset(
                                        pagerState,
                                        tabPositions
                                    )
                                    .height(0.dp)
                                    .size(0.dp)
                            )
                        }) {
                        tabTitles.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
                            val tabColor = remember {
                                Animatable(white)
                            }

                            val textColor = remember {
                                Animatable(ash7a)
                            }

                            LaunchedEffect(key1 = pagerState.currentPage == index) {
                                tabColor.animateTo(if (pagerState.currentPage == index) pearl else white)
                                textColor.animateTo(if (pagerState.currentPage == index) white else ash7a)
                            }

                            Tab(
                                selected = pagerState.currentPage == index,
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .padding(8.dp)
                                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(25.dp))
                                    .background(
                                        color = tabColor.value,
                                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(25.dp)
                                    ),
                                onClick = {
                                    scope.launch {
                                        pagerState.animateScrollToPage(index)
                                    }
                                }) {
                                Text(
                                    tabTitles[index],
                                    modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 10.dp),
                                    style = TextStyle(
                                        color = textColor.value,

                                    )
                                )

                            }

                        }
                    }
                    HorizontalPager(
                        count = tabTitles.size,
                        state = pagerState,
                    ) { tabIndex ->
                        Text(
                            text = tabTitles[tabIndex],
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
```

Please refer this link and download video for more clearity of the problem. When the tab is clicked.. it takes some delay for the indicator to change to the selected tab.Ihave to show the green indicator to the selected tab immedietly when its clicked.

https://github.com/harishpadmanabh-HP/Game-Arena-Compose/blob/master/VID-20220413-WA0000.gif.mp4

Comment: Check out [Why isn't it good to ask multiple questions in one question?[https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371614/why-isnt-it-good-to-ask-multiple-questions-and-answers-in-one-question].

Comment: Also please update your code to [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Right not it's not possible to run it.

Comment: Please check now @PylypDukhov

Comment: Your code still have a lot of unknown variables, like `ash7a`, `pearl`, etc, and is using `R` resources. Make sure I can run it just by copy-pasting to my empty project. Also perfectly add gif illustrating your problem.

Comment: I have added the codes and video . Please check and help @PylypDukhov

Answer (score 0):

`animateTo` is a suspend function: it will finish processing when the animation ends.

As you need to run two animations in parallel, you can launch a child coroutine:

```kotlin
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    launch {
        tabColor.animateTo(if (pagerState.currentPage == index) pearl else white)
    }
    textColor.animateTo(if (pagerState.currentPage == index) white else ash7a)
}
```

Comment: I tried this but still the problem exists. Still the delay is there. it did not make any changes.

Comment: @HarishPadmanabh Try adding `animationSpec = tween(3000)` for both animation to check out how it looks like both with and without my fix. I believe that what's left is just that background animation looks faster because it's more contrast.